# what is the difference between open TCP scan and half-open (stealth) TCP scan?

Tags: tcp

As what I know, an open TCP scan is just a normal TCP 3-way handshake followed by RST. It is detectable because the target will log this connection.

For the half-open TCP scan, it is defined as "stealth". The explanation is that **only a SYN packet** is sent, which is also a 3-way handshake.

But these two seems same. I do not find what are the true difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is *the initiation* of the 3-way handshake. but the scanner has no intend to complete it. This means it receives the SYN+ACK from the target (now knowing it's there), but never sends the final ACK itself (maintaining stealth).

Comment: Hence, it means the 1st and 2nd steps of 3-way handshake are totally same? Then instead of final ACK, the 3rd step will be RST, or there is no 3rd step?

Answer (score 2):

There will be 3rd step but in stealth scan third step is only RST where as on the other hand third step in Full open scan is ACK+RST.